# Rails 5 upgrade Halt callback config issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have recently upgraded from Rails 4.2 to 5.0. I know about the change in callback halting using throw(:abort) instead of returning false. My problem is that I can't make the deprecation warnings go away.

DEPRECATION WARNING: Returning `false` in Active Record and Active Model callbacks will not implicitly halt a callback chain in Rails 5.1. To explicitly halt the callback chain, please use `throw :abort` instead.

I have made config/initializers/callback_terminator.rb file with following code

```
ActiveSupport.halt_callback_chains_on_return_false = false
```

but I am not still not able to get rid of the warning. Nor am I getting the expected behaviour. It seems that this configuration is not being applied.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Did you restart `spring` after update?

Comment: No. Should I have? I restarted the app but didn't see it anywhere in instruction. How do i do that?

Comment: `spring` is an app preloader for Rails, sometimes it prevents new changes to be applied to your development environment. Please refer to [spring's document](https://github.com/rails/spring#usage)

Comment: It's probably not spring related as spring is only installed for development environment.

gem "spring", group: :development

The issue is being observed in test env as well. 
I have tried restarting the app but to no benefit.

Comment: the environment config files overrides configs on application config file. Maybe check those as well? 
e.g. config/environments/development.rb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the config in after config.after_initialize block in application.rb file like this.

```
config.after_initialize do
  ActiveSupport.halt_callback_chains_on_return_false = false
end
```